# How can I see what has changed in an excel file that is posted on SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, excel

I currently have an Excel file posted on SharePoint 2007 with an alert set up to tell me when it is modified. It works fine, but my question is how can I tell what has changed when I go to review it?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a feature that can be done in SharePoint about any type of file. However Excel 2013 has a feature called Spreadsheet enquire that can show you the differences between 2 versions of the file.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/what-you-can-do-with-spreadsheet-inquire-HA102835926.aspx

That is the closest you can get to what you want to achieve.